# "Invalid key hash. The key hash C/*****************= does not match any stored key hashes" error on Facebook Android app

Tags: android, facebook, hash, facebook-android-sdk

I published my Android app (with Facebook Login integration) with a debug key hash.

I have fixed this by performing:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

which generated a new key hash. I added this key hash to my Facebook Developer app settings:

[image]

and saved the changes.

However I'm still getting the error message:

```
Invalid key hash. The key hash C\MY_OLD_KEY_HASH does not match any stored key hashes.
```

when I log in to my app via Facebook.

So even though I've changed the key hash, the above error message still shows my old key.

Is there somewhere in my actual Android code/resources that I need to add the new key hash?

Comment: The key hash will be different for debug and release . For debug you generate keyhash with debug.keystore file and for release you generate keyhash with your .jks file

Comment: I did generate a new release key: The `<RELEASE_KEY_PATH>` in `keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_PATH> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64` is my `.jks` file

Comment: don't generate new , use the same .jks file which you used to sign your apk to playstore

Comment: I did use the same `.jks` file which I ised to sign the apk to play store. `keytool -exportcert -alias <RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS> -keystore <RELEASE_KEY_WHICH_I_SIGNED_TO_PLAYSTORE> | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`